Repeat animation when user clicks (Jetpack Compose Android)
I spent hours to implement this, but still can't...
Android, Jetpack Compose. I have Text() on a screen with initial alpha 20%. By clicking on it - I need to show animation with alpha from 100% back to 20%. And every time user clicks on Text() - it should animate from 100% to 20%.
Can anybody help me with this?

You can use animateFloatAsState. Here is the implementation for your specific case:
    var targetAlpha by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0.2f) }
    val animationDuration by rememberUpdatedState(if (targetAlpha == 1f) 0 else 2000)
    val alpha: Float by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = targetAlpha,
        animationSpec = tween(animationDuration),
        finishedListener = {
            if (targetAlpha == 1f) {
                targetAlpha = 0.2f
            }
        },
        label = "Alpha Animation"
    )

    Text(
        text = "Tap Me!",
        fontSize = 50.sp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable(
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                indication = null,
            ) {
                targetAlpha = 1f
            },
        color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = alpha)
    )



Thank you! This is close. But in your example it animates from 100 to 20 and also from 20 to 100. I need only animate from 100 to 20, but from 20 to 100 should switch immediately

@EugeneVoronoy answer is updated.
